# Where can I find a comprehensive list of VOIP uris for iPad?

Tags: ipad, uri, voip, skype

As an example, the skype iPad app provides handling for uris of the form:

- skype:+11235551234?call

Since there are multiple VOIP iPad apps, I'm wondering if there's a list of other uri schemes such as for fring, google voice, truphone, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely used protocol in VoIP is SIP, and URIs look like this:

- sip:3333@sip2sip.info